# Remove items in taxonomy entity relation on node edit form

Tags: 8, nodes, taxonomy-terms

If a field on the node edit form is a entity relation to a taxonomy term vocabulary, I want the taxonomy terms be restricted on certain conditions. I don't know how to do it safely. I have tried it in `hook_form alter()`. Deep in the "array stack" of the form variable is the definition of the entity reference form field.

> [image]

Is the only way to "hack" the "#process" array, or is there any object-oriented way to filter the items in the drop down element?
Is there any form "plugin" to filter the items in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2):

You're deep in the field definitions there, that's the wrong place, you can't change anything there and you don't need to.

In case of a select, the available options are already part of the form; they should be in `$form[$field_name]['widget']` somewhere.
You could also try to use [`hook_options_list_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21options%21options.api.php/function/hook_options_list_alter/8.4.x).

Comment: hook_options_list_alter() looks like perfect for this job. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I thought it might. Note that the hook only applies to the widget. Meaning, you can use it to filter/remove options as well as change their labels, but you can't add options as they then wouldn't exist during validation/render